# Trying to post data to firestore using requests

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, python-requests

im trying to post JSON data to firestore using requests and it keeps returning this error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\"data\": \"message\"}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\"data\": \"message\"}' could not be found in request message.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\"data\": \"message\"}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\"data\": \"message\"}' could not be found in request message."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried different method using different types of JSON Encoding and still returns the same error. i would appreciate if someone could look into this for me. Below is my code

```
    def thestream(self, instance):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        s = requests.Session()
        self.data = {u'data': u'message'}
        self.headers = {"authorization": "bearer " + app.idToken}
        r = s.post("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/*******************************/databases/(default)/documents/messages/TemitayoAdefemi", params=json.dumps(self.data), headers=self.headers)
        print(r.ok)
        print(r.content.decode())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try defining a [Document resource](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents#Document) in your payload:

```
self.data = {u'fields': {u'data': {u"stringValue": u'message'}}}
```

In your POST request, try passing the payload in `data=self.data` instead of `param`:

```
r = s.post("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/***/databases/(default)/documents/messages/TemitayoAdefemi", data=self.data, headers=self.headers)
```

Comment: Thank you but got this error `False
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\nfields=data\n^",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
`

Comment: I believe that's because `param` passes the data in the URL. Try using `data=self.data` in your POST request.

Comment: Nice! Please share the fix to help others :-)